# store credit card info into paypal vault and also want to use paypal Buttonsource

Tags: php, security, paypal

I am saving credit card info to the paypal's vault by using REST API. It gives me a token by using it i can make process further. But the problem i have to use paypal's button [ButtonSource] that is tracking total sales via paypal. So how can i use both ?

one other thing by using token i am able to get all details of card that is saved. In case if my code will be compromised then any one can steal my tokens saved in database and get the details. How can i make it secure ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is some feedback from PayPal on this one:

The Parameter ButtonSource is a parameter of our classic API's and is currently not supported with the REST API. The Rest API's are still in early stages and we will see much more Features added over the next 12 months. So even the parameter might not be supported with REST now, it can be soon. However, with REST as of now, the merchant would need to use other parameters to track his payments.

---

one other thing by using token i am able to get all details of card that is saved. In case if my code will be compromised then any one can steal my tokens saved in database and get the details. How can i make it secure ?

---

Technically, if the merchants System is hacked and his credentials + DB is exposed to a third party, they can lookup details using this API:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#look-up-a-stored-credit-card

However, we won't return the full card number and the CVV is not stored on our end as well. So from that perspective the merchant is grand. However, they need to make sure that their credentials are secured and not accessible for third parties.